# How can i retrive data from shared prefrances by on click or on click listiner?

Tags: java, android

```
 public void saveData(View view) {

   SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor myEditor = mySharedPreferences.edit();


   savedPage = pdfView.getCurrentPage();
   myEditor.putInt("retrievedPage",savedPage);
   myEditor.apply();
   if (true){
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "تم حفظ الصفحة", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   else {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "لم يتم حفظ الصفحة", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```

}

public void RetriveData(View view){
SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

```
savedPage = mySharedPreferences.getInt("retrievedPage",0);

pagenumber = savedPage;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. I put it in on create and get it from on click.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    savedPage = mySharedPreferences.getInt("retrievedPage",0);

    pagenumber = savedPage;

public void retriveData(View view){

     finish();
     startActivity(getIntent());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to retrieve data from shared preferences.

To write data:

```
SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("AUTHENTICATION_FILE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor myEditor= preferences.edit();
 savedPage = pdfView.getCurrentPage();
   myEditor.putInt("retrievedPage",savedPage);
   myEditor.apply();
```

To Read data:

```
  SharedPreferences prfs = getSharedPreferences("AUTHENTICATION_FILE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Int savedPage = prfs.getInt("retrievedPage", "");
```

Comment: Ok i know that but if i put read data in on click listener its not working

Comment: you can get the data from shared preferences when your activity or fragment is created and you can store them in any variable and then you can set the data into your local variable to perform operation on it. It isn't necessary to get the data on click of button you just have to get the data on create of the activity and then you can store it and use it anywhere in your activity or fragment

Comment: Yes i restored the data in oncreate and its working but i need a button restored the data too can you help me in this ?